# Form service cannot establish connection using the app but works in browser

Tags: html, regex, angular

Hello friends I'm developing a small app with login and a basic interaction with a REST server, but have a BIG problem i cannot understand.
In the simple HTML login form have the traditional two fields (login/passwd) and a sibmit button, when I'm working in the browser (ionic serve) all works fine, the credentials arrive to the server and this one check if is correct and allow to continue (the normal behaviour) BUT if i generate the apk and installl in a phone (ionic cordova build android) it doesn't work and NO request arrive to the server so i cannot login and do anything.
The login HTML is:

```
            <form class="ui form segment" id="formLogin" action="<?=$router->pathFor('login-check')?>" method="post">
              <div class="content">
                <div class="ui required field">
                  <label>Usuario</label>
                  <input name="usuario" id="usuario" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="ui required field">
                  <label>Contraseña</label>
                  <input name="contrasena" id="contrasena" type="password">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="ui hidden divider"></div>
              <div class="actions">
                <div class="ui primary submit button" id="btnAdicionar">Iniciar sesión</div>
              </div>
              <div id="errorInput" class="ui negative message hidden"></div>
            </form>
```

The page.ts file with the method have:

```
login(form) {
     this.Datos.login(form.value.usuario,form.value.password).subscribe(data => {
      if(data.uid){
        ...
        this.router.navigate(['tabs/tab1']);
      } else {
        ....
      }
    });
  }
```

In the service the code have:

```
login(usuario,pw): Observable<any>  {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        "Accept": 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      })
    };

    let datos = {
      "usuario": usuario,
      "passwd": pw
    }

    return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}/autenticar`, datos, httpOptions);
  }
```

As I say this works fine in browser and no in the APK installer.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does your `baseUrl` resolve to?

Comment: whats the error you are getting and whats the url you are hitting

Comment: The baseURL resolve to my server FQDN (www.xxxx.xxxx) and works fine, if I show the variable it have the correct value. the most extrange is IT WORKS in the browser :'(

Comment: The error is if I hit the submit button the app doesn't send the request to the server.